# Setting Hibernate Fetch/Batch size in Spring-Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, configuration

I have a query, which is expected to return ~500.000 elements, which have to be postprocessed. The elements are loaded from a spring-boot app with JPA/Hibernate. To increase the overall speed of the operation I use the `getResultStream` instead of `getResultList`.

Still, the speed of the operation seems to low. I experimented with the hibernate fetch-size, which should be applicable here.

In my `application.yml` the fetch size is set in

```
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        jdbc:
          batch_size: ...
```

When I put the logger `org.hibernate.cfg` to debug, I can see that the values I set are printed out. However, they seem to have no effect whatsoever. Whether the fetch size is set to 1, 10 or 2000 the time for executing the code never differs.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If you are postprocessing large volumes, the reading isn't going to be the bottleneck but rather the writing, especially if you are trying to update all 500000 records at once and never flush and clear the first level cache.

Comment: Also the property is `hibernate.jdbc.batch_size` as this value is used as is, you should add that as the name in yaml and not indented like you have now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, we just learned the hard way, that SqlServer ignores the fetch size in the default SELECTMETHOD=DIRECT and simply always transfers the whole `ResultSet` as is. Therefore, any changes in the fetch size will have no effect when executed against SqlServer unless you change the SELECTMETHOD to CURSOR (which will slow your queries down *a lot*).

My issue was therefore not with hibernate but with the underlying database.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are simply not doing anything wrong and it just takes the database that long to fetch all the data from disk and send it to your application.

One thing you can try is to use a `StatelessSession` or try to clear the persistence context after every e.g. 20 elements by doing `entityManager.clear()`. Maybe the slowdown is due to the persistence context filling up with all those elements and causing memory pressure.

Without any further information, it's impossible to help you though.

Answer (score 0):

In the entity, use the assigned generator since MySQL IDENTITY will cause insert batching to be disabled. If you have auto increment id, batch will not work. I used @Id and provided UUID, batch worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).